# How do I fix Stored XSS and Reflected XSS?

Tags: security-review, stored-xss, xss, reflected-xss

When submitted my code for force.com scanning, I got a few error in the report which are "Reflected XSS and Stored XSS". So, would like to know if these are due to the usage of "jQuery, javascript and CSS" or due to other reasons. Is there are a way to fix these, if so, please help me as I would want to submit the application for code review.

Best Regards

Answer (score 7):

Lets first understand what is XSS and see what are the possible ways to prevent this

> **Cross-site scripting(XSS)** is a vulnerability that occurs when an attacker can insert unauthorized JavaScript, VBScript, HTML, or other active content into a web page viewed by other users. A malicious script inserted into a page in this manner can hijack the user’s session, submit unauthorized transactions as the user, steal confidential information

**Mechanism provided in VF to Overcome this issue**

**1)Built in Auto Encoding**

All merge-fields are always auto HTML encoded provided they

i)do not occur within a  or  tag

ii)do not occur within an apex tag with the escape='false' attribute

**2)Built in VisualForce encoding functions**

The platform provides the following VisualForce encoding functions:

> JSENCODE -- performs string encoding within a Javascript String
>   context
>
> HTMLENCODE -- encodes all characters with the appropriate HTML
>   character references so as to avoid interpretation of characters as
>   markup.
>
> URLENCODE -- performs URI encoding (% style encoding) within a URL
>   component context
>
> JSINHTMLENCODE -- a convenience method that is equivalent to the
>   composition of HTMLENCODE(JSENCODE(x))

There is a detailed article in below link

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_Cross_Site_Scripting

**Sample example**

```
<div onclick="this.innerHTML='Howdy {!Account.Name}'">Click me!</div>
```

The above is vulnerable

Lets see how we use Encode functions to rectify this

```
<!-- safe -->
 <div onclick="this.innerHTML='Howdy {!JSENCODE(HTMLENCODE(Account.Name))}'">Click me!</div>
```

The above is safe since we have use HTMLENCODE AND JSENCODE to encode and hence its hard for attacker to inject script or insert iframe

Comment: Thanks @mohit for the reply and briefing out on XSS. I could understand partially of what is mentioned in your comment and from the referral link provided. But, I am not certain on where exactly to make changes in the VF page to overcome this. Is it possible to provide any kind of examples for the ones mentioned in your reply.

Comment: Added explanation .Wherever you see merge field used without any apex tag or merge field inside javascript  its vulnerable to attack and hence JSENCODE or HTMLENCODE