# Reflected XSS issue

Tags: apex, visualforce, xss

I have found this issue when I have given my code to Code Scanner

> Reflected XSS

This is basically because of two things

```
    Map<string,string> params =
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters();


var validAddress = '{!validAddress}';// it is in VF Page where valid Address is String in apex class
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: those code is not enough to figure out what is that issue

Comment: but what can I say from this -- try to use JSENCODE and HTMLENCODE to ensure that there are no JS injected in validAddress variable (http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/61377/18189) as well as using escapeSingleQuotes on page parameters to avoid injection there

Comment: If it is VF page use: var validAddress = '{!JSENCODE(validAddress)}';

Answer (score 0):

The risk that scanner is alerting you to is that a hacker could put malicious code in a URL parameter.  The parameter values (and names, I suppose) are data from an outside source, and should not be trusted.
     Because of the legitimate risk, you should implement the suggestions from kurunve above:  encode and/or escape the parameters as appropriate for the context that you are using them in.

Comment: We can't tell what relationship (if any) exists between `params` and `validAddress`. Certainly the snippet is not enough to assess if a legitimate vulnerability exists.