# How to solve Reflected XSS error in query referenced in my Visualforce Component

Tags: apex, visualforce, security-scanner

When I sent my code to security scan I got Reflected XSS error. How to solve this issue? I wrapped the variable with Jsencode. Visualforce component is not saving. Below is the code where I got that error.

```
if('{!sfield}' !=''){
 $elem.select2("data", {id: "{!new}", text: "{!sfield}"})  
}
```

Comment: Without seeing your code members will guess and might mark unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I got Reflected XSS Error. At below lines of code                                                               
   if('{!sfField}' !='')                                                                                                            {
    $elem.select2("data", {id: "{!newField}", text: "{!sfField}"})  
 }

Answer (score 3):

Lets first understand what is XSS and see what are the possible ways to prevent this

> Cross-site scripting(XSS) is a vulnerability that occurs when an
>   attacker can insert unauthorized JavaScript, VBScript, HTML, or other
>   active content into a web page viewed by other users. A malicious
>   script inserted into a page in this manner can hijack the user’s
>   session, submit unauthorized transactions as the user, steal
>   confidential information

**Mechanism provided in VF to Overcome this issue**

**1)Built in Auto Encodin**g

All merge-fields are always auto HTML encoded provided they

i)do not occur within a or tag

ii)do not occur within an apex tag with the escape='false' attribute

**2)Built in VisualForce encoding functions**

The platform provides the following VisualForce encoding functions:

> JSENCODE -- performs string encoding within a Javascript String
>   context
>
> HTMLENCODE -- encodes all characters with the appropriate HTML
>   character references so as to avoid interpretation of characters as
>   markup.
>
> URLENCODE -- performs URI encoding (% style encoding) within a URL
>   component context
>
> JSINHTMLENCODE -- a convenience method that is equivalent to the
>   composition of HTMLENCODE(JSENCODE(x))

There is a detailed article in below link

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_Cross_Site_Scripting

Sample example

```
<div onclick="this.innerHTML='Howdy {!Account.Name}'">Click me!</div>
```

The above is vulnerable

Lets see how we use Encode functions to rectify this

```
<!-- safe -->
 <div onclick="this.innerHTML='Howdy {!JSENCODE(HTMLENCODE(Account.Name))}'">Click me!</div>
```

The above is safe since we have use HTMLENCODE AND JSENCODE to encode and hence its hard for attacker to inject script or insert iframe

**Edit**

For your code try like below

```
if('{!JSENCODE(sfield)}' !=''){
 $elem.select2("data", {id: "{!JSENCODE(new)}", text: "{!JSENCODE(sfield)}"})  
}
```

**Edit 2**

> Use the **String** function to wrap the sfiled because JSENCODE only accepts
>   TEXT

```
if('{!JSENCODE(String(sfield))}' !=''){
     $elem.select2("data", {id: "{!JSENCODE(new)}", text: "{!JSENCODE(String(sfield))}"})  
    }
```

Here is the answer that I did refer: - 
[Source](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/61376/how-do-i-fix-stored-xss-and-reflected-xss)

Comment: I have already tried like that before. It is giving me error "Incorrect argument type for function 'JSENCODE()'. : Markup"

Comment: What is the data type of **sfield** and **new** field

Comment: public object sfield {get; private set;}  private object sfield {get; private set;}

Comment: **JSENCODE** always receives **Text** Parameters so try to use **.valueOf** function. Edited the Anwer

Comment: Sorry use **String(sfield)** to convert into text

Comment: I doesn't worked for me. I'm getting error. "Unknown function String. Check spelling.: Markup". JSENCODE works in Javascript. My code is in Jquery , so we can't use JSENCODE in Jquery?